# How to access OpenGL ES 2 via C++/NDK if EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE is not supported?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

My application (written in C++ with a Java bootstrap code) is running perfect on my Android MID device, but it's not working on a friend's Moto MB865 phone.
After digging with the GL context creation procedure, I found the `EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE` is `GL_FALSE` for all configurations which support OpenGL ES 2.0

It means I cannot access OpenGL ES 2.0 with my native code.

Why does the system has this strange restriction? I thought the native code can access all the OpenGL configurations before this.

Is there any way to work around this restriction? Or do I have to write a delegate to access EGL2 via JNI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EGL_NATIVE_RENDERABLE` has nothing to do with the NDK.

It just indicates the capability of the native rendering API to draw to buffers.

Refer to EGL spec: http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.pdf
Paragraph `2.2.3 Interaction With Native Rendering`:

> Native rendering will always be supported by pixmap surfaces (to the
>   extent that native rendering APIs can draw to native pixmaps). Pixmap
>   surfaces are typically used when mixing native and client API
>   rendering is desirable, since there is no need to move data between
>   the back buffer visible to the client APIs and the native pixmap
>   visible to native rendering APIs. However, pixmap surfaces may, for
>   the same reason, have restricted capabilities and performance relative
>   to window and pbuffer surfaces. Native rendering will not be supported
>   by pbuffer surfaces, since the color buffers of pbuffers are allocated
>   internally by EGL and are not accessible through any other means.

The reason of your problem should be different (GLES 2.0 unsupported, etc.).